# Overload operator+ in C++

Tags: overloading, operator-keyword

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Matrix.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string inputStr;
    cin >> inputStr;
    Matrix m1(inputStr);

    cin >> inputStr;
    Matrix m2(inputStr);

    cout << "m1: " << m1 << " m2: " << m2 << endl;   


    cout << "m1 + m2: " << (m1+m2) << endl;   // problem does not print result of m1+m2 


    return 0;
}

// Here is the part of cpp program for Matrix class that overload operator "+"
const Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix &M2)const
{
    if((isLegal==true)&&(M2.isValid()==true))
    {
        if ((cols == M2.getCols()) && (rows == M2.getRows()))
        {

            Matrix result(rows, cols);

            for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
                {
                    result.mat[x][y] = (mat[x][y]+M2.getMat()[x][y]);
                }
            }
    cout << result << endl;  // Here it prints OK the result Matrix but in main
                             // program after return it does not print ???
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return Matrix();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Matrix();
    }
}

// Here is the part that overload "<<" for Matrix
ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const Matrix &M2)
{
    if ((M2.getCols() != 0) && (M2.getRows()!=0))
    {
        os << "|";
        for (int x = 0; x < M2.getRows(); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < M2.getCols(); y++)
            {
                os << M2.getMat()[x][y];
                if (y <M2.getCols() - 1)
                {
                    os << ",";
                }
                else
                {
                    os << "|";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        return os << "invalid matrix!";
    return os;
}
```

From running the program it seems that the result of m1+m2 is not returned ok to main program and I have no idea what is wrong !!!
inside the method of overload the "+" operatot the result of m1+m2 is printed OK but after "return result" in Main it does not print using "<< (m1+m2)"

Comment: it was a tipo mistake